# Fetching a specified amount of columns

Tags: php, mysql, database

I currently have a function that outputs the table structure information [column names]:

```
function PizzaHeaderOutput(){
$pdo = $GLOBALS['pdo']; // Accessing the global scope of the $pdo variable
$stmt = $pdo -> prepare("DESCRIBE Pizza");
$stmt->execute();
$fields = $stmt -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN); // Fetch each column (each separate header)
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($fields as $value){ // Take each field as a value within the header
    echo "<th>$value</th>"; // Output each header
}
echo "</tr>";
}
```

My question is how do I output only a certain number of headers [column names] and not all of them.

The `$fields = $stmt -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);` method is obviously fetching all (5) headers, and I am asking if there is an equivalent method to 'fetchAll' which would take a specified number.

I am hoping to output headers 1-3.

Comment: why exactly would you want to do this. what's wrong with storing those column names in an array??

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the specified number of field names, you can try this:

```
    $query = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schema_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name' LIMIT ?, ?;"    
    $stmt = $pdo -> prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $start, PDO::PARAM_INT); // start column
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $count, PDO::PARAM_INT); // count fields
    $stmt->execute();
```

It working with MySQL